# How to access multiple dictionary keys within for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, tuples, python-itertools

The following is a sample dictionary with multiple keys per value array:

```
test_dict = {('CA', 1): [1,2,3,4], ('MT', 45): [5,6,7,8]}
```

I would expect that looping over the keys with `itertools` would yield the tuples:

```
import itertools

for key, value in test_dict.iteritems():
    print key
```

However, this yields the first item in each tuple

```
MT
CA
```

How can I access the tuple within each iteration but still have access to the values, for example:

```
('CA', 1)
('MT', 45)
```

My ultimate objective is to be able index the tuple within each iteration. For example in this example I would index the tuple and access the second tuple item:

```
for key, value in test_dict.iteritems():
    print key[1]


1
45
```

Comment: Your code works for me. `for k, v in {('CA', 1): [1,2,3,4], ('MT', 45): [5,6,7,8]}.iteritems(): print k` prints `('MT', 45) ('CA', 1)`

Comment: What version of Python are you using ? Your first code example prints out tuples in Python 2.7 and I can index the tuple using `key[0]` and `key[1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = [k for k,v in test_dict.items()]
```

Output:

```
[('MT', 45), ('CA', 1)]
```

To get the elements of `lst`:

```
for i in lst:
        print (i)
```

Output:

```
('MT', 45)
('CA', 1)
```

...and getting the first element of the tuple:

```
for i in lst:
        print (i[0])
```

Output:

```
MT
CA
```

...or the second element of the tuple:

```
for i in lst:
    print (i[1])
```

Output:

```
45
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `keys()` method instead, this way:

```
>>> test_dict = {('CA', 1): [1,2,3,4], ('MT', 45): [5,6,7,8]}
>>> 
>>> test_dict.keys()
[('MT', 45), ('CA', 1)]
>>> for k in test_dict.keys():
    print k

('MT', 45)
('CA', 1)
```

Or even simply:

```
>>> for k in test_dict:
    print k


('MT', 45)
('CA', 1)
```